# turn column that has numbers and some dash to int?

Tags: python, pandas

This column:

```
x['bags']
```

has this:

```
bags
1
34
12
13
3
12
-
11
1
```

I want to turn it to `int` because it is an object type.

I want to use it in `groupby` like this:

```
x.groupby(['user'])['bags'].sum()
```

and gives:

> TypeError
>   : 
>   unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

so turning it to int would solve this. Tried this:

```
x['bags'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

but has problem with the dashes.

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Comment: Use `pd.to_numeric(x.bags, errors='coerce')`, then `fillna` with whatever you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errros=coerce` for convert non numeric to `NaN`s and another values to `float`s (because `NaN` is `float` by design) and then aggregate `sum` with column `x['user']`:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'bags': ['1', '34', '12', '13', '3', '12', '-', '11', '1'], 
                  'user': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']})
print (x)
  bags user
0    1    a
1   34    a
2   12    a
3   13    a
4    3    b
5   12    b
6    -    b
7   11    b
8    1    b

df = pd.to_numeric(x['bags'], errors='coerce').groupby(x['user']).sum().reset_index()
print (df)
  user  bags
0    a  60.0
1    b  27.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.to_numeric(x['bags'], errors='coerce'))
0     1.0
1    34.0
2    12.0
3    13.0
4     3.0
5    12.0
6     NaN
7    11.0
8     1.0
Name: bags, dtype: float64
```

Comment: non numeric to NaNs and another values to float.What are the another?

Comment: @user10351750 - another means numeric saved as strings - floats and integers.

Comment: Can this be done inplace somehow?

Comment: @user10351750 - I think not.